# How to read password protected excel file without office intrope

Tags: asp.net, excel, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

i need to read password protected excel file but my web server did not install microsoft 
excel application. so how do read password protected excel file....

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx) is a blog post that deals with that.  Looks like you need to change

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

to

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```